# Qual o código pra imprimir apenas o primeiro numero de um valor? ex: só o 8 do 8372883

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int a, b, c, d;
    printf("Insira um numero de quatro digitos: ");
    scanf("%i",&a);
    b=a%10;
    c=a%100;
    d=a%1000;
    printf("%i\n%i\n%i\n%i",a,d,c,b);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

### Primeiro digito

Para obter apenas o primeiro digito de um numero, pode calcular a quantidade de dígitos utilizando logaritmo de base 10 e com essa quantidade obter apenas o primeiro digito através de uma divisão.

Exemplo com o numero `123`:

- Calcular logaritmo de base `10` que dá `2` que é a quantidade de dígitos menos 1.
- Criar um fator de `10` levantado ao numero anterior, `2`, ou seja `10^2` que dá `100`
- Efetuar uma divisão inteira entre `123` e `100` que dá `1` e corresponde ao primeiro digito

Em c no seu código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    int a;
    printf("Insira um numero de quatro digitos: ");
    scanf("%i",&a);

    int digitos_menos_1 = log10(a);
    int fator = pow(10, digitos_menos_1);
    int primeiro_digito = a / fator; //a é o numero
    printf("%i", primeiro_digito);

    return 0;
}
```

[Veja a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/1sQsop)

Note que tive adicionalmente de incluir a biblioteca `math.h` para poder utilizar a função [`log10`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/log10/) e a função [`pow`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/log10/).

### Todos os digitos

Agora se o objetivo é mostrar todos os digitos como dá ideia no seu código original então é melhor seguir por outro caminho, caminho este que regra geral é mais fácil até.

Para isto pode pegar no valor original e obter o ultimo digito com o operador modulo sobre `10`, fazendo `% 10`, depois divide o valor por `10` para eliminar o ultimo digito que já foi utilizado. Repete este processo até que o numero chegue a `0`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int a;
    printf("Insira um numero de quatro digitos: ");
    scanf("%i",&a);

    printf("Digitos a começar pelo ultimo:\n");
    while(a != 0){
        printf("%d\n", a % 10); //imprimir só o ultimo
        a /= 10; //eliminar o ultimo
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Veja este também no Ideone](https://ideone.com/nkTc9m)

Repare que os dígitos foram mostrados pela ordem inversa, partindo do que está mais à direita. Consegue também fazer o inverso, pela esquerda mas é necessário optar por outras soluções ligeiramente mais complicadas.

A mais direta é mesmo utilizando recursividade, assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void imprime_digito(int numero){
    if (numero != 0){ //se não terminou por chegar a 0
        imprime_digito(numero / 10); //chama de novo para o próximo digito
        printf("%d\n", numero % 10); //imprime
    }
}

int main(){
    int a;
    printf("Insira um numero de quatro digitos: ");
    scanf("%i",&a);

    printf("Digitos:\n");
    imprime_digito(a); //chama a função recursiva

    return 0;
}
```

[Código a correr no Ideone](https://ideone.com/qtWFnE)

Comment: +1 por usar Log pra calcular o divisor sem precisar usar while. Obrigado, aprendi uma coisa legal hoje :D

Answer (score 0):

Assim?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int a, primeiro;
    printf("Insira um numero: ");
    scanf("%i",&a);

    primeiro=a;
    while(primeiro >= 10)
    {
       primeiro = primeiro / 10;
    }

    printf("Primeiro digito = %d", primeiro);

    return 0;
}
```

Val para qualquer número, independentemente do número de dígitos.

Comment: é um codigo que bota junto com %i, mas acho que controla as casas decimais apenas...